# How to share data between Django templates and view methods without using sessions?

Tags: python, django, session, data-structures

I'm working on a web application (Python/Django), and I need to share python sets and dictionaries between rendered pages.

From now, I was using Django sessions to transfer those data structures. The problem is that they are quite big, and it takes too much time to load them in my "views.py" functions and to put them back in sessions after modifications.

To sum up : my data structure is created in views.py then transfered in a template, then used and modified in views.py then transfered again in a template (the same) etc...

So, how to share data between templates and views without using sessions ?

Comment: You can use context processors for this purpose - it injects context variables

Comment: Read/write the data to a database.

Comment: Also, using context processors in conjuction with middleware can be really useful. It might help to include an example of the sort of data you're "sharing" and how you're currently doing it.